# while and return in a loop (Haskell)

Tags: loops, haskell, for-loop, while-loop

How to code the following pseudo-code elegantly in Haskell?

```
for (i from 0 to 100):
    for (j from 0 to 100):
        k=0
        while ( f(i,j,k) >0 ):
            return (i,j,k)
            k+=1
```

where `f` is an unimportant function of `i`,`j`and `k`.

So it should output something like this: `[(0,0,0),(0,0,1)..]`, a list with each element a tuple formed by `i`,`j`and`k`. (It's fine if it were of the form `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1]...]` instead of tuples.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
[ (i,j,k) |
  i <- [0 .. 100],
  j <- [0 .. 100],
  k <- takeWhile (\k -> f i j k > 0) [0 ..] ]
```

This is a list comprehension that loops over `i`/`j` in the obvious way, and uses `takeWhile` to limit `k` by the result of `f`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming with `return` you actually mean Python-like `yield`, otherwise the algorithm wouldn't make sense.

Using `do` notation, this is very straightforward:

```
do
    i <- [0..100]
    j <- [0..100]
    k <- takeWhile (\k -> f i j k > 0) [0..]
    return (i, j, k)
```